# take another textfield while in listener

Tags: java, jframe, textfield

[image]

I dont using 2 label for this calculator.I can calculate problems with 2 label.But when I was trying with 1 label i cant.Exactly my problem is here.

```
private void jButton9MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
        a=Integer.valueOf(jTextField1.getText());
        jTextField1.setText("");
        b=Integer.valueOf(jTextField1.getText());
        c=a+b;
    }
```

I took 1 number from textfield to 'a' parameter.But i wanna take one more text from textfield.But after `jTextField1.setText("");` this I cant `b=Integer.valueOf(jTextField1.getText())`; line ofc. How can i fix this? ty for help

Comment: So each time an operator is called (+, -, ect), you take the value and place it some kind `List` (along with the operator, maybe in a second `List`), when `=` is pressed, you can perform the calculation. Equally, you could just store the current result of the operation each time a operator is called and simply update the current result

Answer (score 0):

Make `jTextField` variables private global variables with public `get` and `set` methods.

Also, do not use `Mouse Event Listener` for buttons, you should be using `Action Listener`

Also your order of operations is wrong. Your total is calculated when the '=' is pressed.

You have the following in the text field

3

You press button 9, and what's it going to do just do 3+3=6 That's not what you want, i assume.

That's not how a calculator works.

- Step 1) Enter a value.
- Step 2) Enter a symbol
- Step 3) Enter a new value, check if there is a symbol in the text field. Is so, get total.

This is how it would work, but that's just bad logic in it's own.

**The proper way to do it would be:**

- Step 1) Press any number or symbol on the calculator except for 0 until you're satisfied and append them to the text field.
- Step 2) Press = sign
- Step 3) Take the entire string from the text field and parse it, check if it is proper math in a try catch and then let java evaluate it.

Comment: Ty for comment so  I cant do anything with my code ? any changing not possible without using action listener?

Comment: @Vodka Morello you can use `Mouse Listener`, you shouldn't but you can. I'm not fixing your code for you though when the logic is wrong. You don't have two numbers to get, just **one**. I explained above what to do and you can google simple java calculator for examples.

Comment: no i dont claim for fixing.Just asked for knowledge. Ty for much help.I know is ez.But am trying new fancies :D am checked out but idk what to do now ty again :D

Comment: No problem, i explained what to do :) `The proper way to do it would be`. So let the user enter whatever they want and add it to the text field. Then when they press `=` and only them, do math :)

Comment: my math brain loop  always slacker :D ty for understanding and sorry my fault english